# How to remove axis hover-info in plotly.js?

Tags: javascript, plotly

So, the problem and question is in title. I just can't find a way, to disable the tooltips, that appear on the axis on hover. Maybe I'm missing something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set [`hoverinfo`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#scatter-hoverinfo) to show only the information you are interested in.

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17, 8],
  type: 'scatter',
  hoverinfo: 'y'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9],
  type: 'scatter',
  hoverinfo: 'x+y'
};

var trace3 = {
  x: [0, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [16, 4, 12, 7],
  type: 'scatter',
  hoverinfo: 'all'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, {});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
```